# pd.read_csv give Illegal instruction (core dump)

Tags: python, pandas, conda, librosa, illegal-instruction

I am using miniconda3 to create virtual environment in linux aarch64. The following packages are installed in the virtual environment.

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
_tflow_select             2.3.0                       mkl    anaconda
abseil-cpp                20200923.3           h01db608_0    conda-forge
absl-py                   1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.8.1            py37h795501a_1    conda-forge
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             4.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
asynctest                 0.13.0                     py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     22.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
audioread                 2.1.9                    pypi_0    pypi
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
bottleneck                1.3.5            py37h297e572_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h4e544f5_7    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h4e544f5_7    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h795501a_1004    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                hf897c2e_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               hf897c2e_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.6.15            h4fd8a4c_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.6.15        py37hfd236b0_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.6           py37habb7ed1_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3            py37hfd236b0_0    conda-forge
cryptography              37.0.4           py37h6427ddf_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               2.0.6                h4de3ea5_0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.34.4           py37h795501a_0    conda-forge
fpdf                      1.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               hbbbf32d_2    conda-forge
frozenlist                1.3.1            py37h795501a_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.4.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                hb9de7d4_2    conda-forge
google-auth               1.35.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.46.3           py37h1fda7f6_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.6.0           nompi_py37hd4e5f7a_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.1          nompi_h7bde11e_104    conda-forge
icu                       68.2                 h3621d8e_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.11.4           py37hd9ded2f_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       5.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h9cdd2b7_2    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.9.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras                     2.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h4e544f5_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4            py37h020193f_0    conda-forge
kneed                     0.7.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               h7c456eb_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 h012adcb_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-aarch64     2.36.1               h02ad14f_2    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h4de3ea5_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           16_linuxaarch64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h4e544f5_7    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h4e544f5_7    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h4e544f5_7    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           16_linuxaarch64_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.83.1               h8fd98b7_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.13                 h4e544f5_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h884eca8_2    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.1.0              h3242a24_16    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.1.0              he9431aa_16    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.1.0              h41d5c85_16    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.1.0              h3242a24_16    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           16_linuxaarch64_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               h75cb1c7_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                hf897c2e_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.21          pthreads_h6cb6f83_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hf9034f9_3    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.14.0               hc71ff50_0    conda-forge
librosa                   0.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
libssh2                   1.10.0               h1ab2c7b_2    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.1.0              hd01590b_16    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                hb3f8b40_3    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            hf897c2e_1000    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.3                hef792ef_1    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.3                h4e544f5_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h3557bc0_1004    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h4e544f5_2    conda-forge
llvmlite                  0.39.0                   pypi_0    pypi
logger                    1.4                      pypi_0    pypi
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h01db608_1    conda-forge
markdown                  3.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.1            py37heeccf27_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.2            py37hf63bfc2_1    conda-forge
multidict                 6.0.2            py37h795501a_1    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  headf329_1    conda-forge
numba                     0.56.0                   pypi_0    pypi
numexpr                   2.8.3            py37h1ee7537_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.6           py37h0edd665_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h45037e0_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h4e544f5_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.5            py37h337a648_0    anaconda
patsy                     0.5.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pickle5                   0.0.12           py37hcd4c3ab_0    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0            py37h2dc4c6d_0    conda-forge
pip                       22.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pooch                     1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.14.0           py37had24c86_1    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hb9de7d4_1001    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.1           py37heeccf27_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37hd9ded2f_5    conda-forge
python                    3.7.9           h3bd6a85_100_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-flatbuffers        1.12               pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
python-levenshtein        0.12.2           py37h795501a_2    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     2_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                1.3.0            py37h297e572_1    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py37h795501a_4    conda-forge
rdp                       0.8                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h38e3740_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
resampy                   0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.9                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py37hcb2b5d4_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.3            py37hd18d958_0    conda-forge
seaborn                   0.11.2               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
seaborn-base              0.11.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                64.0.1           py37hd9ded2f_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.9                hc7e91e1_1    conda-forge
soundfile                 0.10.3.post1             pypi_0    pypi
sqlite                    3.39.2               hc74f5b8_0    conda-forge
statsmodels               0.13.2           py37h297e572_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.0            py37h3144da0_0    anaconda
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.5.0           mkl_py37h0d38317_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           2.5.0           mkl_py37ha7bf56e_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh81a9013_1    conda-forge
termcolor                 1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               hd8af866_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.3.0                hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.3.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022b                h191b570_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0           py37h795501a_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.11            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
watchdog                  2.1.9            py37hd9ded2f_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.35.1             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.14.1           py37h795501a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h3557bc0_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h3557bc0_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h6dd45c4_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                hf897c2e_2    conda-forge
yarl                      1.7.2            py37h795501a_2    conda-forge
zipp                      3.8.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               h4e544f5_2    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                haad177d_4    conda-forge
```

While installing all the packages with conda, "librosa" cannot install with conda. So I tried installing "librosa" using mamba. Mamba gives the below error

```
Pinned packages:   - python 3.7.*   Encountered problems while solving:   - nothing provides audioread >=2.0.0 needed by librosa-0.6.1-py_1
```

So I tried to install audioread with mamba `mamba install audioread`. It gives this error

```
Pinned packages:   - python 3.7.*   Encountered problems while solving:   - nothing provides requested audioread
```

I also tried installing audioread with conda. Conda cannot install. So I install audioread with pip  `pip install audioread`. Audioread with version 3.0.0 can install successfully via pip. Then I install librosa with mamba `mamba install librosa` I got the same issue

```
Pinned packages:   - python 3.7.*   Encountered problems while solving:   - nothing provides audioread >=2.0.0 needed by librosa-0.6.1-py_1
```

So I install librosa with pip `pip install librosa` librosa can install successfully via pip.

In the python, when I read the csv file using pandas `df=pd.read_csv("test.csv")` I get `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

**May I know how can I solve this issue?** If it is related to package installing using both conda and pip, **how can I install librosa**? Because I also tried creating new environment `conda create -n myenv librosa python`. It gives

```
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                        failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package python conflicts for:
python
librosa -> python[version='>=3.6']
librosa -> decorator[version='>=4.0.10'] -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=2.7|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.5|>=3.7|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0',build='*_73_pypy|*_cpython|*_cpython|*_73_pypy|*_cpython|*_73_pypy']
```

But when I create new environment only install pandas and python, read the csv file. It gives no error.

**Edit:** I have already tried downgrading my version of numpy, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70542780/11659881). But it does not solve the issue.